# Firebase: does BigQuery doesn´t export some events data?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

This is my first question in StackOverflow. I´m sure it will be useful and I hope you can help me!

This is my problem: In the context of Firebase data model, importing a datasource from Data Studio GA4 I found that both for Android and iOS there are lot of *purchase* events that doesn´t display information about the *currency* parameter (it shows as not set).
[Data Studio output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZpug.png)

In order to analyze this issue, we went to BigQuery so we can could take a look to the raw data. There, we found that in the iOS case the biggest problem is that the *revenue* parameter of the *purchase* event is being sent as string, when the official documentations indicates that it should be sent as double_value.

**But for the Android cases we are still confused**, since we can´t find in BigQuery any case in which the *revenue* parameter is being implemented as string nor it doesn´t have the *currency* parameter set. So my specific question is: is there a possibility that the BigQuery export doesn´t include the *purchase* events that doesn´t have the *currency* parameter implemented? Or do you have any other suggestion on what might be happening?

Thanks in advance!